# Using CKEditor inside blade template [Laravel 3.x]

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, laravel-3, laravel-blade

I'd like to use this bundle: [laravel-ckeditor](https://github.com/villimagg/laravel-ckeditor)
but I have troubles in nesting it in my view (all previous installation steps I've done successfully).
How can i connect Form::text() with this bundle?

When I add

```
<?php 
        $ckeditor = new CKEditor();
        $config = array();
        $config['toolbar'] = array(
            array( 'Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike' ),
            array( 'Image', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' )
        );
        $events['instanceReady'] = 'function (ev) {
            alert("Loaded: " + ev.editor.name);
        }';
        $ckeditor->editor("field1", "
        Initial value.

        ", $config, $events);
    ?>
```

it simply creates new text area but unfortunately without any richtext functionality...
Does anyone has already met this problem?

Comment: I've also tried http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/laramce but I have no idea how to properly use it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example of working TinyMCE:

```
<!-- title field -->
    <p>{{ Form::label('title', 'Tytuł') }}</p>
    {{ $errors->first('title', '<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close">×</a>:message</div>') }}
    <p>{{ Form::text('title', $value = $post->title, $attributes = array(Input::old('title'))); }}</p>
<!-- body field -->
<p>{{ Form::label('body', 'Tekst') }}</p>
        {{ $errors->first('body', '<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close">×</a>:message</div>') }}
        <p>{{ RTE::rich_text_box('body',$post->body,array('att'=>array('id'=>'editorID'),'selector'=>'editorSelector','mode'=>'full','setup'=>array('skin'=>'o2k7','skin_variant'=>'black'))) }}
        </p>
    <!-- submit button -->
        <p>{{ Form::submit('Edit') }}</p>
```

the trick was to use it INSTEAD of Form::text (and change all file permissions in /laravel/public/bundles/* for 0755)
the same thing was about CKEditor. hope it will help others in a future (:

Answer (score 0):

**steps are**:

1. install the editor first via composer by running the command:

   `composer require unisharp/laravel-ckeditor`
2. Add this to ServiceProvider in `config/app.php` to the providers array:
   `'providers' => [`

   `Unisharp\Ckeditor\ServiceProvider::class,`
3. back at the command line again, **Publish the resources**:

   `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=ckeditor`
4. Now to embed it into a `textarea` bind them with an `id`

```js
<script src="{{ url('/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'your_id' );
</script>
```

```html
<textarea id="your_id"></textarea>
```

> for these steps they had their own [github repository](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor#installation)

---

**NOTE:** if you are using Laravel Collictive to add the textarea and bind the `id` to it use this:

```
{{Form::textarea('desc', '', ['id' => 'your_id'])}}
```

**AND** then display the nice formatted content like this:

```
{!!$post->desc!!}
```

where `$post->desc` is the returned stored value from the database