# laravel ckeditor dark theme

Tags: php, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

> Hello every one,

I searched the web for a dark skin for the CKEditor and how to actually insert it.

i just wanna share how I got it to work simply **and I actually made what I think an interesting edit on *the official dark one***

I posted this question with the answer here because I didn't find any related topic here. and I would like to share this very specific knowledge and solution in an easy elaborated way to make it easier and straight to every one

**plus** this is a complete dark theme not as the official one.

*thanks*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Here is the Detailed Answer:

- first install CKEditor, if you're using it for laravel project [follow these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46838583/4846859)
- after successfully get it to work, [Download this skin folder](https://github.com/BiskremMuhammad/ckeditor-basic-moono-dark-biskrem) to CKEditor `skins` folder, for laravel you will find it in the path:

```
public/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/skins
```

- right after **pasting** the skin folder into the `skins` Directory, open `config.js` form CKEditor Base Directory - `public/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor` for laravel - **AND Replace its content with this:**

```php
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2017, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For complete reference see:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' }
    ];

    // Remove some buttons provided by the standard plugins, which are
    // not needed in the Standard(s) toolbar.
    config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';

    // Set the most common block elements.
    config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

    // Simplify the dialog windows.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';

    config.skin = 'ckeditor-basic-moono-dark-biskrem';
};
```

---

### RESULT

here is a screenshot

[image]

---

### EXPLANATION

```
// The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' }
    ];
```

**this to minify the editor to the basic tools only**

and finally this line of code:

```
config.skin = 'ckeditor-basic-moono-dark-biskrem';
```

**to actually skin the editor to our dark theme** *`ckeditor-basic-moono-dark-biskrem` implies the skin folder name in `skins` folder*